# Can you edit PDF accessibility tags using code?

Tags: pdf, accessibility, adobe, tagging

I have been tasked with adding accessibility tags (h1, h2, p, figure, etc.) to about 1k PDFs, and it's slow progress doing it one by one in Adobe Acrobat Pro. Is there a library that helps me add these tags to PDFs? I know python, JS, TS, Java, etc.

I was looking at this, Adobe's Autotagging-API: https://developer.adobe.com/document-services/docs/overview/pdf-accessibility-auto-tag-api/

But the results are so bad that I would just be checking them after and I'd end up doing the same job I'm doing now...

Any ideas whatsoever about this task would be appreciated. AI PDF object recognition? Feeding text to ChatGPT and asking it to add the tags?

Many thanks.

Comment: Adobe has an Auto-tag REST API that does a nice job. You can test it on your files at the URL below and then create an account and do it via the API if it works out for you. https://documentservices.adobe.com/dc-accessibility-playground/main.html#

Comment: Thanks, hopefully this will knock out the easier ones. I submitted a request for access, since it looks like it's still in an early access program? Did you get access?